Using Custom Typefaces with PowerApps
I’ve been looking into finding a way to add an existing typeface (OTF file) into my PowerApp, but I need the user to fill in a form on the page, every example I’ve found uses images in the desired typeface to circumvent this, but I need to have actual text that then gets put into an excel sheet.
Please help :’( I’m a beginner so the more detail the better!
I tried to import the file through the formatting bar, but then realized it won’t work on devices that don’t have my typeface installed.
